# Passing a value to Jquery dialog when in a loop

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I want to use Jquery dialog to display notes on a page which has multiple rows called from a database - each row will have a link to show a dialog which should display the relevant content for that row.

The dialog works fine but I cannot get it to take a value from the link so I can then query the database in the div which dialog displays.

When someone clicks the image I want it to display the note for that row - this is the code I have so far. I know I am not sending a value as I don't know how to - how can I get this to attach the row id to the image on each row and then make it available in dialog when the dialog opens so it shows that note?

```
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#jui-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, 
    title: "Note", 
    modal: true, 
    width: "640", 
    buttons: [{
            text: "Close note", 
            click: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }}]
});
    $("#jui-dialog-mdl-btn").bind("click", function(event) {
    $("#jui-dialog").dialog("option", {modal: true}).dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<while begins>
<img src="/icons/16/note.png" title="View employee note" alt="View employee note" id="jui-dialog-mdl-btn">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>">
<while ends>



                        <div id="jui-dialog">
                            <div class="dialog-inner">
                                <?php                                   
                                $query=mysql_query("SELECT content from notes WHERE id='$id'");
                                $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
                                $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
                                $note=$row['content'];
                                print $note;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: NEVER use id in a while loop, since you cannot use two identical id's on the same page. You can use class though.
You can use this code of yours,:

```
<img src="/icons/16/note.png" title="View employee note" alt="View employee note" class="jui-dialog-mdl-btn">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>">
```

To get the id of the employee:

```
$('.jui-dialog-mdl-btn').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).next('input').val();
        //process whatever you like
});
```

To recieve data you would like to show, you can use a hidden div like this:

```
<img src="/icons/16/note.png" title="View employee note" alt="View employee note" class="jui-dialog-mdl-btn">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>">
<div class="dialoginfo" style="display:none;"><!--code to show in your dialog--></div>
```

And then in jquery:

```
$('.jui-dialog-mdl-btn').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).next('input').val();
    $(this).next('.dialoginfo').dialog(/*options*/);
    //process whatever you like
});
```

Of course your implementation can be different but I hope you have anough snippets here